# Connecting to Multiple "Dynamic" Databases Along With Local "Static" Database in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm building an application using Java and Spring Boot where I want to query two foreign databases (they might have different schemas and data) every time I run. Therefore I'd like to query two different databases every time. After accessing those databases, I would then like to store the result (my business logic) on a local static database.

I originally wanted to store all the database data (user, pass, url) in the application.properties, but then realized that this might not be best practice as the details for the two DBs I'm querying will be received as input from the user. Therefore, I'm not sure if it's the best idea to update and overwrite application.properties every time I receive a new request (please let me know if there's a better way to do this.

Assuming I have the DBs info in application.properties, I've followed multiple tutorials for multiple DB connections in Spring, and they all followed something along the lines of making configuration files for each DB, calling a repository/DAO file for each DB, which references a model of said DB. That seems a bit problematic for me as I don't know the schema of the databases before hand, so I can't define a model class. And even if I did, this will probably change across databases, so I'm really not sure what to do.
Is there a more flexible/versatile way to query "foreign" databases with Spring or old school Java given that I don't know what their schemas might look like?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Multiple databases config have to be maintained in `application.properties` or config class as a best practice. Refer here - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources

You can have a POJO with DB properties which gets assigned from user provided values. Use that POJO in a DB config class to connect to different databases.

Not knowing schema is not a problem as you can handle data with java collections.